# insert list in db as foreign key value

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have that db

[image]

And Student can have multiple Subjects. So I'm storing them like that:

> StudentId: 1, Name: Math; StudentId: 1, Name: Geography

etc..

I have subjects in Viewbag:

```
ViewBag.Subjects = new SelectList(new[] { "Math", "Phisic", "Chemic", "English" }
                .Select(x => new { value = x, text = x }),
                "Value", "Text");
```

And user can select multiple items at once. 
When I'll register new student It must insert that student's subjects as well. For them I'm that:

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Register([Bind(Include = "Id,Name,Surname,BirthDate,Gender,Subject")] Students student)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                SubjectsList();
                return View();
            }
            Student _student = new Student();
            _student.Name = student.Name;
            _student.Surname = student.Surname;
            _student.Gender = student.Gender;
            _student.BirthDate = student.BirthDate;

            Subject _subject = new Subject();
            if (!student.Subject.Any())
            {
                foreach (var item in student.Subject)
                {
                   _db.Subjects.Add(item);//Here it throws an exception Wrong overload
                }
            }


            _db.Students.Add(_student);
            await _db.SaveChangesAsync();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

And my **Students** class is here:

```
public class Students
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public DateTime? BirthDate { get; set; }
    public List<string> Subject { get; set; }
}
```

***My question is how can I add that subject values in my Subject table***

Comment: And the question is...

Comment: i think you are trying to achieve something similar to this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33515256/creating-a-model-that-can-take-an-array-of-parameters

Comment: this could also help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33538544/passing-a-list-of-checkbox-to-controller

Comment: @venerik I've updated my question

Comment: and you have a different table for saving the subjects? and that means you need to be updating both the tables while saving a student. you could use the answer in the links to save it in two different tables.

Comment: @ViniVasundharan yes. see image on the top of the question (I've linked it)

Comment: INSERT is used to add values to a table. (And UPDATE to update values.)

Comment: @jarlh I know.. I want to insert these values..

Comment: Personally, I think your data model is wrong; you can have subjects without students, right?  And what about two students sharing a subject?  Really, what you probably want is to remove `studentId` from the subjects table, and create a new "cross-reference" table with just `studentId` and `subjectId` in it.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse and if I'll to that how can I assign subjects to students? can u provide some sample?

Comment: students are related to subjects by an entry in the cross-reference table (Let's call it `StudentSubjects`).  I'm not sure how this plays out WRT EntityFramework, though - I'm more used to the db side of things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your classes should look like this:

```
public class Subject
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public virtual List<Student> Students {get;set;}
}

public class Student
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public virtual List<Subject> Subjects {get;set;}
}
```

You can then add subjects to students like this:

```
var subject = new Subject 
{ 
    Name = "Physics" 
};
_db.Subjects.Add(subject);

var student = new Student 
{ 
    Name = "venerik", 
    Subjects = new List<Subject> { subject }
};
_db.Students.Add(student);
_db.SaveChanges();
```

In this set up EF will create a table for both Student and Subject and an intersection table called SubjectStudent (as @Clockwork-Muse already suggested).

Answer (score 1):

I am going to refrain on the potential for improving your data model to better reflect reality for now *(as there is already some great discussion on this in the comments)*, so given the constraints of what your actual data model looks like, here's my answer:

> The way EF (and plain old Linq-To-SQL) are designed handles foreign
> key relationships at the ORM level, so that you do not have to.
>
> The ORM entities generated by EF where foreign keys are involved create one-to-many relationships as List objects, and these are called `navigation properties`. [This article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564.aspx) sheds some light on how this works.

Thus, you do not need to add the individual `subjects` to the `Subject` table explicitly;

Since the `Student` and `Subject` tables have a foreign key relationship, having the `List<Subject>` on the `Student` objects is sufficient and EF will handle the inserts for you.

---

**A note on the exception you're getting:**

Your current code has a list of strings for subjects on the student class:

```
public List<string> Subject { get; set; }
```

Then you are trying to insert the strings into the _db.Subjects (`DbSet<Subject>`) instance, which is why you're getting the exception.

---

**Solution:**

- Make a `Subjects` class that mimics your EF Subject table  *(since it appears you're creating custom classes to mimic the ORM entities, which is a practice I personally like since it decouples the ORM from the final consumer of the data such as your front end)*
- Change the `Students` class to have `List<Subjects>` instead of `List<string>` for the Subjects property.

Then your code to insert the records would look something roughly like this:

```
Student _student = new Student();
_student.Name = student.Name;
_student.Surname = student.Surname;
_student.Gender = student.Gender;          
_student.BirthDate = student.BirthDate;

// I removed the ! here because it seems pointless to check that you have no elements, and then try to add them....
if (student.Subject.Any())
{
    foreach (var item in student.Subjects)
    {
         // this is the ORM subject now, the names seem ambiguous 
         // but the important thing is you have are filling the List<Subject>
         // of the Student ORM entity with Subject ORM entities,
         // which will cause the ORM to handle the foreign key relationship
         // and insert items into the Subjects table

         _student.Subjects.Add(new Subject() { 
             Name = item.Name
         });

         // Note: the ORM will handle the StudentId field, and I assume
         // the Id field is an SQL Identity and will be auto-generated;
         // If not then, aside from, 'why not?', you'd populate it manually
    }
}
```

Then you still just do `_db.Students.Add(_student);` and it will work.